# Import big XML into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, import, mysql-workbench

I have to import the following XML file into MySQL. I can only get the row "Name" to work. The import doesn't work because on "Class", "Subclass", etc. there is an additional "Name" tag inside.

I also have to import the "PropertyData", but how do I do that?
The XML File can't be changed under any circumstances!

```
<MatML_Doc>
<Material>
   <BulkDetails>
       <Name>ABS</Name>
       <Class> <Name>PLASTIC</Name></Class>
       <Subclass> <Name>ABS Polymer</Name></Subclass>
       <PropertyData property="Material_Type">
           <Data format="string">IsotropicMaterial</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Version">
           <Data format="string">4.0</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Category">
           <Data format="string">PLASTIC</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Mass_Density__RHO_NonIso__6">
           <Data format="exponential">1.050000e-006</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Mass_Density__RHO__6">
           <Data format="exponential">1.050000e-006</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Youngs_Modulus_E_NonIso__31">
           <Data format="exponential">2.000000e+006</Data>
       </PropertyData>         
       <PropertyData property="Youngs_Modulus_E__31">
           <Data format="exponential">2.000000e+006</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="PoissonsRatio__1">
           <Data format="exponential">4.000000e-001</Data>
       </PropertyData>         
       <PropertyData property="PoissonsRatio">
           <Data format="exponential">4.000000e-001</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="MatlNonlinearityType">
           <Data format="integer">1</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="YieldFunctionCriterion">
           <Data format="integer">1</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="HardeningRule">
           <Data format="integer">1</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Yield_Strength_32">
           <Data format="exponential">4.000000e+004</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Thermal_Expansion_A_NonIso__34">
           <Data format="exponential">7.000000e-005</Data>
       </PropertyData>         
       <PropertyData property="Thermal_Expansion_A__34">
           <Data format="exponential">7.000000e-005</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Thermal_Conductivity__K__35">
           <Data format="exponential">1.700000e+002</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Specific_Heat_CP__23">
           <Data format="exponential">1.800000e+009</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="Crosshatch_Pattern">
         <Data format="string">Rubber/Plastic</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="CoatingsStudioMaterialName">
         <Data format="string">ABS Plastic</Data>
       </PropertyData>
       <PropertyData property="CoatingsVisualizationColor">
         <Data format="exponential">168, 168, 168</Data>
       </PropertyData>
   </BulkDetails>
</Material> FILE CONTINUES....
```

My Code so far:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testdb;
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
USE testdb;

CREATE TABLE bulkdetails (
    Name VARCHAR(40),
    Class VARCHAR(40),
    Subclass VARCHAR(40));

LOAD XML INFILE "C:\physicalmateriallibrary.xml"
INTO TABLE bulkdetails
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<BulkDetails>';
```

Comment: MySQL can import plain XML only whereas your file is nested. Process it using string functions.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Show destination table's CREATE TABLE. Edit sample data, make sample XML complete, and show desired importing result for it.

Comment: @Akina  hey, how does that exactly work? my google cant find anything helpfull under "xml to mysql with string function" can you suggest a site where I can read exactly that?

Comment: Just treat the value not as XML, but as a regular text string.